# Bevel uneven on symmetric selection (not scale or duplicate geometry)

Tags: modeling, bevel

For some reason bevel is coming out lopsided despite the original geometry being perfectly symmetrical. 
[image]

I checked to make sure scale was applied and that there was no duplicate geometry or extra geometry attached causing the sides to not be identical.

One of the sides is directly on the x axis and the verticies on either side are offset by the same amount down to .00001 as shown below

[image]

[image]

Its like that all the way down each side. When I select more edges all the way around it bevels symmetrically as I would expect.
[image]

What could be causing the original bevel to be so lopsided given that the selection is symmetrical, without duplicates and with scale applied?

I found that this issue can be recreated from the default cube with 4 loop cuts and 2 extrudes. Its more pronounced when the middle loop cut is removed, but present in both cases.
[image]

Blend file with the default cube version here [image]

Comment: Hello. Please consider uploading your .blend file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so others can take a look. Without that it's just guessing :).

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6763" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6763/)   I hope I added this correctly.

Comment: Hey there. Source file works, and I was able to replicate your issue. Lets go investigate :).
Btw. Thanks for preparing the blendfile so nicely.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. I am using 2.79, I wonder if its present in 2.8 as well. I'm hesitant to call it a bug, but it really doesn't seem like the expected or desired behavior.

Comment: Blender 2.8 here. And the behavior gets way crazier once I start to experiment with different bevel options - vertices are jumping all over the place with no apparent reason. It seems you really found a bug - and a rather nice one at that. Congrats :).

Comment: I should probably report it to the developers. Not quite sure how to go about doing that, guess I will have to look into that. Thanks so much for checking it out and letting me know its still present in 2.8 as well.

Comment: Hey Jachym, the bug was confirmed by the developers and given a medium priority. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I was wondering how it went. And good job on helping with Blender development, it's really nice to be a part of such an active community. Have a nice day.